# Gradle workflow with project dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm wondering how people develop day-to-day with Gradle and how they manage in-house dependencies.

Let's say we have a main project with the following in-house dependencies:

```
proj depends on dep1
proj depends on dep2
proj depends on dep3
```

Now, these dependencies also may depend on one another:

```
dep1 depends on dep2, dep3
```

I want to be able to basically develop them simultaneously, where I have a main project(proj) and all it's depencies (dep1, dep2, dep3) open in, say, IntelliJ or some other IDE. That way, when code in one project changes, I can tell the IDE to build and run and it will take care of building the dependencies for me. Also, the code is evolving rather rapidly and this allows me to immediately see where I've made certain errors between projects.

Right now, in the build.gradle file for proj, I have something like the following for dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project('ext:dep1')
    compile project('ext:dep2')
    compile project('ext:dep3')
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

where the other dependent projects are checked out from source control into $proj/ext/dep[1..3]. This is great and all, but then I have to worry about dep1 and its dependencies. Now I could do the same kind of thing recursively where dep1 would also have dep2 and dep3 checked out into $proj/ext/dep1/ext/dep[2..3], but then dep1 would not be updated when I update $proj/ext/dep[2..3].

I feel like this could be something that is fixed maybe with a symlink or something, but I'm wondering if I'm just way off the mark on how day-to-day development should go.

This could also be solved by having a binary repository (Archiva, Nexus, etc.), but I feel like the process of building a dependency, pushing to the repository, then having Gradle download it during the build process is too complex for what it is. Not to mention this would involve having a separate IntelliJ window open for every project and dependency, whereas with the scenario described above, it's 1 window with dependency projects open. I also don't get the benefit of knowing immediately when I have an issue.

I want to keep this as generic as possible so that any other developer could clone this repo and instantly be ready to go without having to make sure the paths line up relative to their situation. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: When using maven and eclipse, the m2eclipse plugin allowed you to resolve snapshot dependencies as projects. This allows you to edit all of the projects and update each other without having to build artifacts. Is this what you want with gradle?

Comment: Edit: And now that I think about it. I think it's a very bad idea to use Archiva or others to host intermediary snapshots in this case because there couldn't be other developers working with the same library at the same time or they risk overwriting each other's artifacts.

Comment: @Taylor, It sounds like that may be a step in the right direction. I'm hoping to preserve the fact that I could want to check out the whole "proj" repo or just the "dep1" repo. I don't want to tailor my build.gradle for the dependencies as if they would only ever be opened, or depended on by this one project.